# Metal fragment shader get size

Tags: ios, metal

Is there a way to retrieve sizes of Frame Buffer & buffers passed in Metal fragment shader, or we need to manually pass them as arguments? I wish to retrieve the width and height of Frame Buffer texture to which results are being written as well as length of other MTLBuffers ([[buffer(0)]], [[buffer(1)]],...) passed to the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

That information is not automatically available. You have to pass it in as arguments.

Comment: Don't we even have view port size available in shader?

Comment: Nope. You have the Metal Shading Language specification, don't you? If it's not in there, it's not available.